# How can I select a store for pickup at checkout

Tags: checkout, multistore

We're looking to insert a drop-down list at checkout so buyers need to select their preferred shop location so they can pick up the goods. We don't need an inventory management. Can anyone recommend an extension for this or is it a custom job?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many stores, a quick solution can be to install a module that gives you multiple flat-rate shipping methods (such as http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping-1.html) and rename every shipping method to a store location (e.g. pick-up at store x), and give it a price of $0. You'd probably need to do some customization to get the UX right (dropdown maybe, or rename "Shipping" step to "Pickup at store" or something, but it could work.

Comment: Good idea but there's over a dozen stores so that wouldn't quite work but really appreciate the idea.

Comment: Thanks - I understand. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with any modules that do this..